# Failed to create session factory AMQ219007 when sending messages to AMQ Artemis from Camel JMS component

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I try to send messages from the Camel rout JMS component, on some messages the error below occurs. Out of 50,000 messages, 4937 reached an average speed of 497 mes/sec. At the same time, with the same settings, the classic ActiveMQ gives about 10,000 mes/sec

Artemis version 2.11.0. Camel version 2.20.2

Error

```
Error while routing: Message has put to DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE
 org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:516)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:440)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:394)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:132)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:445)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        ... 19 more
        Suppressed: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
            ... 19 more
            Suppressed: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
                ... 19 more
            Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
                at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
                at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
                at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294)
                at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
                at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
                ... 16 more
            Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
                at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:799)
                at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
                ... 20 more
        Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294)
            at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
            at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
            ... 16 more
        Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:799)
            at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:799)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:799)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
    ... 20 more
```

Camel route

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans factor:name="Send to Artemis" factor:status="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:factor="factor-schema"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf               http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">
    <camelContext errorHandlerRef="myDeadLetterErrorHandler"
        id="e726891b-7413-4428-9bf5-f6c85116c771" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <interceptFrom>
            <bean method="updateMDC" ref="logInterceptorService"/>
        </interceptFrom>
        <route factor:name="Send to Artemis" id="route-4cd627f9-ba6d-43e3-ba24-4f61d8c1b69b">
            <from id="35ecd8c3-ea1e-48ee-8d1e-85815576242c" uri="timer://init?delay=-1&amp;repeatCount=50000">
                <description>Timer</description>
            </from>
            <setBody factor:component="SetBodyEndpoint"
                factor:custom-name="Установить тело сообщения"
                factor:guid="endpoint-34546317-7707-4c92-9d08-c388ea6cc390" id="endpoint-34546317-7707-4c92-9d08-c388ea6cc390">
                <simple><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Header>
    <props:MessageInfo xmlns:props="urn:cbr-ru:msg:props:v1.3">
      <props:To>uic:5454</props:To>
      <props:From>uic:newuser</props:From>
      <props:AppMessageID>guid:1134f9d42bc98c84caea7ee62c17881312</props:AppMessageID>
      <props:MessageID>guid:1429e234ae7016f981111361</props:MessageID>
      <props:MessageType>1</props:MessageType>
      <props:Priority>5</props:Priority>
      <props:CreateTime>2016-07-27T12:41:13Z</props:CreateTime>
      <props:LegacyTransportFileName>20191008 # pacs.008.001.08 # AAAACNBJXXX # BBBBRUMMYYY # 123456789.xml</props:LegacyTransportFileName>
      <props:SendTime>2016-07-27T12:41:14Z</props:SendTime>
      <props:AckRequest>false</props:AckRequest>
    </props:MessageInfo>
    <props:DocInfo xmlns:props="urn:cbr-ru:msg:props:v1.3">
      <props:DocFormat>1</props:DocFormat>
      <props:DocType>ED311</props:DocType>
      <props:EDRefID EDNo="1" EDDate="2016-07-27" EDAuthor="1203709000" />
    </props:DocInfo>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <sen:SigEnvelope xmlns:sen="urn:cbr-ru:dsig:env:v1.1">kk
    </sen:SigEnvelope>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>]]></simple>
            </setBody>
            <setHeader factor:component="SetHeaderEndpoint"
                factor:custom-name="Установить заголовки"
                factor:guid="87ba2d3e-7eff-42cd-9efc-048764539364"
                headerName="JMSDeliveryMode" id="87ba2d3e-7eff-42cd-9efc-048764539364">
                <constant>NON_PERSISTENT</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <wireTap id="18382f84-1f34-487e-a55a-a731e1ec9560" uri="jms://TEST.FROM.CAMEL?connectionFactory=#RemoteArtemisMQ">
                <description>JMS</description>
            </wireTap>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <bean
        class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
        factor:bean-type="DEFAULT" id="RemoteArtemisMQ" name="RemoteArtemisMQ">
        <constructor-arg value="tcp://192.168.58.6:61619"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Artemis config

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 83.33 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 12000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>12000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


      <page-sync-timeout>84000</page-sync-timeout>


            <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61619?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

I pointed out for Artemis **-Xmx6G**, but it didn’t affect anything, only about 5-7% of the allocated memory is consumed

Please tell me why this error occurs and how to improve performance?

Comment: I had a different version of the artemis jms client in the project, after I strictly indicated which version to use, the error went away

Comment: Did you ever start seeing the performance you expected?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine after I fixed the error.

Comment: You should add whatever you did to resolve the issue as an answer and mark it as correct to help others who run into this same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a different version of the artemis jms client in the project, after I strictly indicated which version to use, the error went away